# Can we calculate the point on Earth nearest to the Moon?

Tags: astronomy, error-analysis, moon, eclipse

We have the ability to calculate the Moon's orbit in order to predict Lunar and Solar eclipses precisely.

Using our known calculations of the Moon's orbits, can we calculate the closest point (city or coordinate) on Earth to the Moon for any future or past date and time?

If so, how?

Comment: The short answer would be yes. It is the point on Earth where the moon is straight overhead.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  I'd like to track the points on earth that are closest to the moon during it's monthly and yearly cycles over a decade.  Do you know the formula for that, or perhaps where I can find this information?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a website which gives you this information? eg :  http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html?iso=20160105T1732

Comment: Not specifically that address, but I did search Google extensively.  The time and date website is the perfect thing...  Thank you!  I don't know how to vote but that is a great answer!